# Torbjörn's Armor Pack and Brigitte's Rally

Tags: overwatch

Brigitte's Rally provides allies with armor, which, unlike her Repair Pack ability, is not temporary and stays until it is removed by damage. Torbjörn's Armor Pack also provides the same kind of armor. The armor from Brigitte's Rally is capped at 150, while Torbjörn's Armor Pack is capped at 75.

How do these interact with each other? What happens when:

1. The ally has some Torb armor left and gets the full Rally armor? Does it go over the max 150 armor because of Torb's leftover armor?
2. The ally receives Torb armor after getting almost the full Rally armor (less than max Rally armor but more than Torb max armor)? Does it get added on top of the Rally armor (over the max Rally armor), does it only replenish up to the max that the Rally armor allows or does nothing happen at all?

Comment: I'm closing this question as the Armor Pack ability [has been removed from the game](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/news/patch-notes/pc/?page=2#patch-51575)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Torbjorn's Armor Pack and Brigitte's Rally fully stack with each other. This means you can be fully affected by both Brigitte's 100 armor from Rally and Torbjorn's 75 armor from Armor Pack, for a total of 175 extra armor.

Comment: Do you have any sources to support your answer or is this just personal experience?

Comment: Just to clarify this means if you have 75 armour from Torb and you get 150 from Brigitte you will have 225 armour at the end of things? I think adding some concrete examples of numbers to demonstrate your meaning rather than just repetition "They full stack with each other" would improve this answer. The question has two specific examples that you could explicitly address here.